# Word - how to put the superscript higher?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, typography

I'm writing a chemistry paper and that involves the use of superscript. My problem is that the superscript is too low for my liking. See the image:

[image: Superscript in Word]

The first one looks okay, but the second one is not nice. How can I put the '-' higher, so that it (roughly) aligns with the top of the 'B'?

I'm using the font 'Georgia' with font-size 12px and letter spacing 1.5. If you need additional information about the used font, please don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 methods you can use. The first is changing the spacing of the character vertically.

1. Type the characters as normal.
2. Select the character to be raised twice, and raise it once using the normal superscript button.
3. Select the character again and open the font dialog box (CTRL + D). Switch to the Character Spacing tab.
4. Set the position to raised. Increase the point (pt) value until the superscript goes up enough to appear as a double superscript.

The other way is to use an alt code character ALT+0175, or you can copy/paste it from this link: https://www.alt-codes.net/

Comment: Hi @Narzard sorry for the late reply. I didn't want to give you the impression that I'm not reading answers - I always do (because I know how frustrating it is when you do not hear anything after giving an answer). It was just quite busy the last few days. However, your solution helped me a lot, so thanks!